# confusion about lists contained in an aggregate, maybe context problem?

Tags: raku

Rakudo version 2020.01

I was writing some throw-away code and did not bother to implement a class, just used a Hash as work-alike. I found some surprising behaviour with lists.

```
class Q1 {}
class R1 {
    has Str $.some-str is required;
    has @.some-list is required;
}

my $r1 = R1.new(
    some-str => '…',
    some-list => (Q1.new, Q1.new, Q1.new)
);

# hash as poor man's class
my $r2 = {
    some-str => '…',
    some-list => (Q1.new, Q1.new, Q1.new)
};

multi sub frob(R1 $r1) {
    for #`(Array) $r1.some-list -> $elem {
        $elem.raku.say;
    }
}

multi sub frob(Hash $r2) {
    for #`(List) $r2<some-list> -> $elem {
        $elem.raku.say;
    }
}

frob $r1;
# OK.
# Q1.new
# Q1.new
# Q1.new

frob $r2;
# got:
# (Q1.new, Q1.new, Q1.new)

# expected:
# Q1.new
# Q1.new
# Q1.new
```

---

`frob(Hash …)` works as expected when I call `.flat` or `.list` on the list (even though it is already a list‽).

I tried to make a minimal test case, but this works identical AFAICT.

```
for [Q1.new, Q1.new, Q1.new] -> $elem {
    $elem.raku.say;
}

for (Q1.new, Q1.new, Q1.new) -> $elem {
    $elem.raku.say;
}
```

---

I have read the documentation on List and Scalar several times, but I still cannot make sense out of my observation. Why do I have to special treat the list in the Hash, but not in the class?

Comment: I get `No such method 'raku' for invocant of type 'Q1'` when I try to run this

Comment: @Håkon Hægland: it used to be called `.perl`: perhaps your Rakudo is not current enough?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`for` doesn't loop over itemized values.

When you place something in a scalar container it gets itemized.

```raku
sub foo ( $v ) { # itemized
  for $v { .say }
}
sub bar ( \v ) {
  for v { .say }
}

foo (1,2,3);
# (1 2 3)

bar (1,2,3);
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

---

An element in a Hash is also a scalar container.

```raku
my %h = 'foo' => 'bar';

say %h<foo>.VAR.^name;
# Scalar
```

So if you place a list into a Hash, it will get itemized.

```raku
my %h;

my \list = (1,2,3);
%h<list> = list;

say list.VAR.^name;
# List
say %h<list>.VAR.^name;
# Scalar
```

---

So if you want to loop over the values you have to de-itemize it.

```raku
%h<list>[]
%h<list><>
%h<list>.list
%h<list>.self

@(%h<list>)

given %h<list> -> @list { … }

my @list := %h<list>;

(my @ := %h<list>)  # inline version of previous example
```

You could avoid this scalar container by binding instead.

```raku
%h<list> := list;
```

(This prevents the `=` operator from working on that hash element.)

---

If you noticed that in the class object you defined it with an `@` not `$`

```raku
class R1 {
    has Str $.some-str is required;
    has @.some-list is required;
}
```

If you changed it to an `$` and mark it `rw` it will work like the Hash example

```raku
class R2 {
    has Str $.some-str is required;
    has List $.some-list is required is rw;
}

my $r2 = R2.new(
    some-str => '…',
    some-list => (1,2,3),
);

for $r2.some-list { .say }
# (1 2 3)
```

It has to be a `$` variable or it won't be in a Scalar container.
It also has to be marked `rw` so that the accessor returns the actual Scalar container rather than the de-itemized value.

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with `[]` versus `()`.  This has to do with the difference between `$` (indicating an item) and `%` (indicating an Associative):

```
sub a(%h) { dd %h }       # a sub taking an Associative
sub b(Hash $h) { dd $h }  # a sub taking an item of type Hash

a { a => 42 };  # Hash % = {:a(42)}
b { a => 42 };  # ${:a(42)}
```

In the "b" case, what is received is an **item**.  If you try to iterate over that, you will get 1 iteration, for that item.  Whereas in the "a" case, you've indicated that it is something Associative that you want (with the `%` sigil).

Perhaps a clearer example:

```
my $a = (1,2,3);
for $a { dd $_ }  # List $a = $(1, 2, 3)␤
```

Since `$a` is an item, you get one iteration.  You can indicate that you want to iterate on the underlying thing, by adding `.list`:

```
for $a.list { dd $_ }  # 1␤2␤3␤
```

Or, if you want to get more linenoisy, prefix a `@`:

```
for @$a { dd $_ }  # 1␤2␤3␤
```

Comment: But in multi sub frob, I'm not iterating over a hash or item, I'm iterating over a array or list accessed by a class's attribute or hash's member. I have verified the types and annotated them at the relevant place with inlined comments.

Answer (score 5):

Not strictly an answer, but an observation: in Raku, it pays to use classes rather than hashes, contrary to Perl:

```
my %h = a => 42, b => 666;
for ^10000000 { my $a = %h<a> }
say now - INIT now;  # 0.4434793
```

Using classes and objects:

```
class A { has $.a; has $.b }
my $h = A.new(a => 42, b => 666);
for ^10000000 { my $a = $h.a }
say now - INIT now;  # 0.368659
```

Not only is using classes faster, it also prevents you from making typos in initialization if you add the `is required` trait:

```
class A { has $.a is required; has $.b is required }
A.new(a => 42, B => 666);
# The attribute '$!b' is required, but you did not provide a value for it.
```

And it prevents you from making typos when accessing it:

```
my $a = A.new(a => 42, b => 666);
$a.bb;
# No such method 'bb' for invocant of type 'A'. Did you mean 'b'?
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me something to link to in a doc I'm writing!  I know someone had said that **class+attributes > hashes** for speed a while back but I couldn't find it.  I'm currently reworking the CLDR module to use attributes whenever with a hash backup (which is surprisingly user friendly thanks to `FALLBACK`)